# I found this example sentence in a book, could you explain it to me?

Tags: grammar

The expression is この近くにトイレがある literally means "this close is a bathroom" I've been studying positions, shouldn't it be ここの近くにトイレがある? 
The grammar rule is:
Placeのpositionにobject がある/いる
ここ is a place so for me the second one have more sense
Help me understand the grammar of the first sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A: この近くにトイレがある
>   B: ここの近くにトイレがある

## Differece in meaning

Basically, "A" means *there is a bathroom in the vicinity of the place where we are now*,
while
"B" means *there is a bathroom in the vicinity of the place where I'm pointing at or the place on a map or like that*.

Of course you can say the phrase "A" by **touching** the place on a map and that makes sense, and you can say the phrase "B" by **pointing at** the ground where we are now.

---

## Grammartical difference

1. **この近く** = この + 近く + に

   - **この** is a 連体詞｛れんたいし｝ *pre-noun adjectival* or *adnominal adjective*,  and it means ***this*** (something or someone close to the speaker (**including the speaker**), or ideas expressed by the speaker).
   - **近く** is a 名詞｛めいし｝ *noun*, and it means *neighborhood or vicinity*
   - **に** is a 助詞｛じょし｝ *particle* which *indicates location*, and it means *in*, *at* or *on*.

The whole meaning of **この近くに** is ***in this vicinity (where I am)***.

2. **ここの近く** = ここ + の + 近く + に

   - **ここ** is a 名詞｛めいし｝ *noun*,  and it means ***here*** (place physically close to the speaker, **place pointed by the speaker while explaining**); this place).
   - **の** is a 助詞｛じょし｝ *particle* which *indicates possessive*.
   - **近く** is a 名詞｛めいし｝ *noun*, and it means *neighborhood or vicinity*
   - **に** is a 助詞｛じょし｝ *particle* which indicates location, and it means *in*, *at* or *on*.

The whole meaning of **ここの近くに** is ***near here (where I am pointing)***.

Answer (score 6):

Either sentence works.  The first one reads, more or less, "In **this** vicinity, there's a bathroom".  Your rewording of it reads, "Close to **here** there is a bathroom."

Both work.  I think the first one sounds more natural if only because it's less wordy.

Don't take your grammar rule too literally.  It more suited to sentences like:

- いすの下に本がある。　　There's a book under the chair.
- 都市のちかくに公園がある。There's a park near the city.

Comment: But how the first one is correct? for example この近くに電話がある? How dois it make sense?, 近く means near right, so how can I say, Is this near (close) a telephone?

Comment: 近く can function as a noun.  This is not true of all adjectives changed to this more (at least I don't think so), but it's definitely true of this one.  As a noun, it might help to think of it meaning "vicinity", though usually in English it will still be translated as "near".  遠く similarly can function as a noun.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, the more adjectives I can think of that can function as a noun, such as, 多く.  But other adjectives like 寒い don't see to have this property.  So, it would be good to hear what a native speaker has to say about this.

Comment: @LuisFernandoBadelMéndez この近くに電話がある? is the same thing: "Is there a telephone nearby?" Just think of この近くに as a set phrase for "nearby" or "in the vicinity of where we are". For "Is this near a telephone?", you'd say (これは)電話の近くですか.